# Linq order based on some other column condition

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I have a list having columns like ID, Name,  Country, State

The order statement needs to be in following way

```
.ToList().OrderByDescending(first=>t.Country).ThenBy(**if state=='GA' then ID else Name**)
```

My question is how to do this ThenBy clause based on some other column condition?

Comment: So it's correct that you don't want to order in the database but in memory? Even then you should not use `ToList` before you start ordering but `AsEnumerable` and append the `ToList` just at the end.

Comment: Thank you Tim for the additional info, sure will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it's correct that you don't want to order in the database but in memory? Even then you should not use `ToList` before you start ordering but `AsEnumerable` and add `ToList` at the end.

```
var resultList = yourQuery.AsEnumerable() // Linq-To-Objects as desired
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Country)
    .ThenBy(x => x.state == "GA" ? x.ID.ToString() : x.Name)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: If `ID` is numeric this completely changes the ordering.

Comment: Thank you Tim/Gert, appreciate your feedback

Comment: @GertArnold: It doesn't change the ordering, it just uses the Id. OP hasn't mentioned what Id is(Guid, Text+Number, fixed length digits like 00023 or really the int-Pk like 123). If the latter i could provide a way to sort numerically.

Comment: If ID is `int` it changes the ordering. No, it's not mentioned, but for others it's something to be aware of.

Comment: @GertArnold how does it change the ordering?

Comment: @user2051770 if ID is an in you get a lexicographical ordering because a String is not an int. That means 100 comes before 2. It's basically comparing each character from left to right